# Unused parameters passed to Capybara::Queries::SelectorQuery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I have spec like this:

```
  it 'contains Delete link' do
    expect(page).to have_link('Delete', admin_disease_path(disease))
  end
```

when I run specs it returns warning in the console:

```
Unused parameters passed to Capybara::Queries::SelectorQuery : ["/admin/diseases/913"]
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
expect(page).to have_link('Delete', href: admin_disease_path(disease))
```

From the [documenting tests](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/spec/session/has_link_spec.rb)